# Compute the double integral $\iint_{(x,y):0<\tfrac{x}{2}\leq{y}\leq\tfrac{3x}{2}<1}dydx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Attempt: I sketched the region, and decided it would be easiest to break up the area into two integrals $A_1,A_2$ and sum. Is it correct that $A_1,A_2$ are Type-I integration regions? Is there a more straightforward way to compute the overall area? My multivar integration is weak.

$$A_1 = \int_0^{\tfrac23}\int_{\tfrac{x}{2}}^{\tfrac{3x}{2}}dydx=\tfrac29$$

$$A_2 = \int_{\tfrac23}^{1}\int_{\tfrac{x}{2}}^{x}dydx=\tfrac{5}{36}$$

Thus the desired integral is $\tfrac{13}{36}$, is this the correct value?

Comment: Why is there an $A_2$ integral at all?  Along that region, $\frac{3x}2 > 1$, so it shouldn't be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region defined by $$(x,y) : 0 < \frac{x}2 \leq y \leq \frac{3x}2 < 1$$
is the triangle enclosed by $y=\frac{x}2$, $y=\frac{3x}2$ and $\frac{3x}2 = 1$ (i.e. $x = \frac23$).

Using the side along $x=\frac23$ as the base, this triangle has height $h = \frac23-0=\frac23$ (the other two lines intersect at $x=0$) and base length $b = \frac{3(2/3)}2 - \frac{(2/3)}2 = \frac23$ (the distance between the points the line $x=\frac23$ intersects the other lines).  It follows that the area enclosed is $$\frac12bh = \frac29.$$